# how to check if map1 contains all of map2 without using containsAll (so use loops and conditionals)

Tags: java

Basically, you are given two maps, map1 and map2. You need to check if map1 contains all the keys that map2 has, and if those keys map to the same value in both maps. If that is the case return true

Heres what I tried:

```
boolean mapContainsOther(Map<String, Integer> map1, Map<String, Integer> map2) {
  assert map1 != null;
  assert map2 != null;
  if (!map1.keySet().containsAll(map2.keySet())) {
    return false;
  } else if (map1.keySet().containsAll(map2.keySet())) {
    for (String s : map2.keySet()) {
      if (map1.get(s) != map2.get(s)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: After checking a condition, no need to test the opposite condition, that's absolutly useless

Comment: *`how to check if map1 contains all of map2 without using containsAll...`* You're using containsAll so be specific on the actual constraints.  First, just compare sizes to make certain `map2` is not larger than `map1`   And just compare entries in `entrySets`. No need to check keys and values independently.